# Using Spring to send an infinite stream of json

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

I found a lot of pages of how to read an infinit stream of JSON. My question is how to produce it using spring boots ?

Actually I've managed to produce a simple json web-services.
This is my pojo :

```
public class Location {

@Id
private long id;

private float x;
private float y;
private float z;
private String timestamp;

public Location(long id, float x, float y, float z, String timestamp) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.z = z;
    this.timestamp = timestamp;
}

public Location(){
    super();
}

public Location(@JsonProperty("id")String id, @JsonProperty("x")String x,@JsonProperty("y") String y,
        @JsonProperty("z")String z, @JsonProperty("timestamp")String timestamp) {
    super();
    this.id = Long.parseLong(id);
    this.x = Float.parseFloat(x);
    this.y = Float.parseFloat(y);
    this.z = Float.parseFloat(z);
    this.timestamp = timestamp;
}

public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public float getX() {
    return x;
}

public float getY() {
    return y;
}

public float getZ() {
    return z;
}

public String getTimestamp() {
    return timestamp;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public void setX(float x) {
    this.x = x;
}

public void setY(float y) {
    this.y = y;
}

public void setZ(float z) {
    this.z = z;
}

public void setTimestamp(String timestamp) {
    this.timestamp = timestamp;
}

@Override
public String toString(){
    return "Location { id : " + id + " x : " + x +
            " y : " + y + " z : " + z + " }";
}
```

}

And this is my controller :

@RestController
public class LocationController {

```
private final RessourcesManager<Location> rm = new RessourcesManager<Location>();

/**
 * @param tagId tag that you want to get the position from
 * @return Location in json format
 */
@CrossOrigin
@RequestMapping("/getjson")
public Iterator<Location> location(@RequestParam(value="tagId", defaultValue="-1") String tagId){
    return rm.getAllElement();
}

@CrossOrigin
@RequestMapping(value="putjson", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public @ResponseBody Location post( @RequestBody final  Location location) {    
      rm.addElement(location);
      return location;
  }
```

}

Using this code I can generate and get a json object.
But just one object...
What I want to do is to go on myurl/getjson and see an infinite stream of data. Not only the return of my iterator..

I read about Jackson Stream API but it looks like it's just to stream into a file... I'm reading about event but if someone can help me on this point....

Thank you !

Comment: I wonder how you would consume that infinite stream. Consuming data for an infinite (or rather indefinite) amount of time doesn't require an infinite stream. Moreover websockets would probably a more appropriate tool for that task.

Comment: I'm looking at websockets and it looks to do what I need ! Thank you for that. If it works I will write some code here.

Answer (score 0):

So this is my new controller :

```
@Controller
public class LocationStreamController {

    @CrossOrigin
    @MessageMapping("/json")
    @SendTo("/locations/location")
    public Location greeting(Location message) throws Exception {
        return message;
    }
}
```

This is my config file :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/locations");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/json").setAllowedOrigins("*").withSockJS();
    }
}
```

Works perfectly ! Thank you for your answer